# Writing data values using OPC UA by set_attribute

Tags: python, opc-ua

I would like to write data via OPC UA using a simple Python script.
For this I use the following code for Boolean values:

```
first_value = Device1.get_objects_node().get_child("2:DeviceSet").get_child("3:BuR").get_child(
    "3:Memory").get_child("3:BoolFlag") #TODO: Pfad Kontrollieren


first_value.set_attribute(ua.AttributeIds.Value, ua.DataValue(False))
```

Now i´d like to change the script for ints

```
first_value.set_attribute(ua.AttributeIds.Value, ua.DataValue(10))
```

But sadly that is not working. Did somone already tried something similar?

Comment: First: Why don't you use set_values() instead of set_attribute() ? Second: I guess the Node has a value of type Boolean ? Trying to write an Int might also be the reason of your error...